# How do I create a custom product types in woocommerce with over 400 child products pulled from categories selected in the data panel?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

How do I create a custom product type in Woocommerce with over 400 child products pulled from categories selected in the data panel ?

I have over 400 products to group, how can I programmatically pull 400 products from certain categories to be grouped, without having to enter each child product manually in the back-end.

I imagine my best bet would be to make a custom product type, but how do I make a custom product type that inherits child products from a certain category.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself yet? Please note that SO is not a code factory

Comment: Hi Derek, as stated on OP, 'I don't need code'. I need some starter points or if its even possible to add a group product programmatically.